# Time domain frequency "loudness" isolation

Tags: fft, time-domain, equalizer

There is a very useful tool in my DAW which allows me to isolate groups of "loudness" within the frequency domain.  Basically, any bin greater than some min, less than some max.  It makes it easy to boost fundamentals, or bring out secondary harmonics; both things which are largely defined by how loud they sound.

This process requires a full FFT and IFFT, and adds a lot of delay.

From what I've seen of filters and eqs, they do not create much of a delay issue; they are able to have mostly isolated effects on frequencies without introducing much lag.  My understanding is that they use tricky time domain maths to do this.

The question is such: **Is it possible to isolate groups by loudness (similar to how filters isolate frequency) without FFT or IFFT?**